# Add a class to a element if a input gets checked

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basicially I like to add a class to a element if a input gets checked.

**Example:**

If the checkbox with the ID "option1" gets checked, I like to add the class "active" to the element with the id "slct-1". If the checkbox gets unchecked I like to add the class "active" again.

```css
.slct-feedback{
margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.slct-option.active{
color: #0095ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="slct-feedback">
<div class="slct-option active" id="slct-1">Option 1</div>
<div class="slct-option" id="slct-2">Option 2</div>
<div class="slct-option" id="slct-3">Option 3</div>
</div>

<label class="option-checkbox">
<span class="sub">Option 1</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="options" value="1" id="option1" checked>
</label>

<label class="option-checkbox">
<span class="sub">Option 2</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="options" value="2" id="option2">
</label>

<label class="option-checkbox">
<span class="sub">Option 3</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="options" value="3" id="option3">
</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the event for all inputs checkbox, and with the value you can add/remove class 'active' to the `#slct-` element.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
  if(this.checked){
    $('#slct-'+this.value).addClass('active');
  }else{
    $('#slct-'+this.value).removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.slct-feedback{
margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.slct-option.active{
color: #0095ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slct-feedback">
<div class="slct-option active" id="slct-1">Option 1</div>
<div class="slct-option" id="slct-2">Option 2</div>
<div class="slct-option" id="slct-3">Option 3</div>
</div>

<label class="option-checkbox">
<span class="sub">Option 1</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="options" value="1" id="option1" checked>
</label>

<label class="option-checkbox">
<span class="sub">Option 2</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="options" value="2" id="option2">
</label>

<label class="option-checkbox">
<span class="sub">Option 3</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="options" value="3" id="option3">
</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

To do this you can use the `toggleClass()` method along with the `checked` property of the checkbox to set whether the class should be added or removed. Try this:

```js
$('#option1').change(function() {
  $('#slct-1').toggleClass('active', this.checked);
});
```

```css
.slct-feedback { margin-bottom: 40px; }
.slct-option.active { color: #0095ff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slct-feedback">
  <div class="slct-option active" id="slct-1">Option 1</div>
  <div class="slct-option" id="slct-2">Option 2</div>
  <div class="slct-option" id="slct-3">Option 3</div>
</div>

<label class="option-checkbox">
  <span class="sub">Option 1</span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="1" id="option1" checked>
</label>

<label class="option-checkbox">
  <span class="sub">Option 2</span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="2" id="option2">
</label>

<label class="option-checkbox">
  <span class="sub">Option 3</span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="3" id="option3">
</label>
```

Note that if your intention is to relate each checkbox to the `slct-option` div you can DRY up the code by using the indexes of the elements to match them up, instead of having to repeat the same event handler:

```js
$('.option').change(function() {
  $('.slct-option').eq($(this).index('.option')).toggleClass('active', this.checked);
}).change();
```

```css
.slct-feedback { margin-bottom: 40px; }
.slct-option.active { color: #0095ff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slct-feedback">
  <div class="slct-option">Option 1</div>
  <div class="slct-option">Option 2</div>
  <div class="slct-option">Option 3</div>
</div>

<label class="option-checkbox">
  <span class="sub">Option 1</span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="1" class="option" checked>
</label>

<label class="option-checkbox">
  <span class="sub">Option 2</span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="2" class="option">
</label>

<label class="option-checkbox">
  <span class="sub">Option 3</span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="3" class="option">
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `input:checkbox`

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('div.slct-option').addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Refer Jquery API ducumentation [`input:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to achieve this using jQuery:

```
inputs = $("input[name='options']");
inputs.each(function(){
  $(this).on('click', function(){
    value = $(this).attr('value');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
       $('#slct-' + value).addClass('active');
    } else {
       $('#slct-' + value).removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

Working [Codepen](http://codepen.io/dragosmicu/pen/MpOXKb).

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$('.option-checkbox #option1').click(function e()
{
    $('.slct-feedback #slct-feedback').addClass('active');
});
```